# casting dabate into human terms

Tags: meaning-in-context

> #### Thousands flock to free medical clinic, as Washington dithers on health care
>
> These events are staged nationwide, but the Wise clinic is among the biggest, drawing people from throughout Appalachia and **casting** Washington’s sterile political **debates into** the starkest human terms.
>
> [Source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/virginia-politics/thousands-flock-to-free-medical-clinic-as-washington-dithers-on-health-care/2017/07/21/07b7d1f2-6d80-11e7-96ab-5f38140b38cc_story.html) (emphasis added)

My question: Does 'casting debate **into**' have the same meaning as 'casting debate **in**' ?

Merriam-Webster learner's Dictionary (learnersDictionary.com) explains 'cast' as

> 7 : to talk about or think of (someone or something) in a particular way
>   example sentence: Health care issues are often cast in economic terms

Comment: [Always cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) – click on the link to see why. (I did it for you this time, but next time you'll know what to do.)

Comment: will do next time.

Answer (score 2):

*In* has two broad senses:

- a stative or locative sense, designating the place where an entity is located, literally or metaphorically:

  > The box is *in* the cupboard.
- a dynamic or directive sense, describing the place to which an entity is moved, literally or metaphorically:

  > He put the box *in* the cupboard.

*Into* has only the dynamic sense:

> He put the box <sup>**ok**</sup>into the cupboard, *but not*
>   The box is <sup>**∗**</sup>into the cupboard.

Consequently *in* and *into* are interchangeable when *in* has a dynamic sense.

As Tᴚoɯɐuo says, we ordinarily use *cast X **in** Y terms* in a more or less stative sense: *Y* is a stative property of the discourse *X*. But *cast* is at bottom a dynamic verb—etymologically it means “throw”—and it is entirely proper for this to replace *in* with *into* when we speak of changing the terms of a discourse, as this author does: by inference he contrasts the “sterile political” terms **in** which the debate has been cast with the “starkest human” terms **into** which it is being cast.

Comment: I've always thought of _cast_ in this usage as a figurative use of the verb as in _to cast a statue_. We do not "throw" the debate into human terms; we _mould_ or _found_ it.

Comment: @P.E.Dant *OED* treats the foundry sense of *cast* as historically derived from *cast* = put into some order or shape; and that, too, seems always to have licensed obliques with both *in* and *into*.

Answer (score 1):

To **cast the debate in {modifier} terms** means to state the issues in a particular manner so that they are seen in a particular light or in relation to a particular concern, referred to by the modifier.

> They cast the debate in fiscal terms.

To **cast into** means to throw something into a place or container.

> They cast the stolen goods into the dumpster and sped away.

Comment: thanks.  then what does ' casting Washington’s sterile political debates into the starkest human terms.' really mean ?